# Value of $x$ when $5 + \log x = \log \left(x^6\right)$

Tags: logarithms

Find the value of $x$ when $$5 + \log x = \log \left(x^6\right)$$

I've tried many times to solve this, however I can't seem to find a correct (consistent) answer.  My solutions range from $$x = e, x = \sqrt 5, x = \sqrt 6$$

Comment: $\log(x^6) = 6\log(x)$, so you should get $\log(x) = 1 \Rightarrow x=e$ (assuming this is a natural log), right?

Comment: Thanks Prahlad.  Yes, natural logarithms.  That was the first answer I got.

Comment: And the fact that $\log x$ is present on LHS guarantees that $\log x^6\neq6\log(-x)$ wich would be the case if $x<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
5+\log x&=\log x^6\\
\Longrightarrow 5+\log x&=6\cdot\log x\\
\Longrightarrow 5&=6\log x-\log x\\
&=5\log x\\
\Longrightarrow 1&=\log x
\end{align}
Your answer from here depends on what base you have for your log function, and if we assume that it is to the base $e$, then $x=e$.

Answer (score 1):

$$5\ln e+\ln x=\ln x^6\rightarrow \ln e^5+\ln x=\ln x^6\rightarrow\ln (xe^5)=\ln x^6\rightarrow xe^5=x^6 \rightarrow e^5=x^5\rightarrow ~~x=e$$

Answer (score 0):

$$5+\log x=\log x^6\implies 5+\log x=6\log x\\\implies 5=5\log x\implies 1=\log x\implies x=e$$, assuming log is the natural log.